# Cin as argument function in c++?

Tags: c++

If I want pass cin as argument function, How is function definition?
For example:

```
ofstream plik("a.txt");
fun(cin, plik);
```

So what is fun Definition?

Comment: you can see the type of cin here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin

Comment: any function taking `std::istream&` can accept `cin` as an argument

Answer (score 6):

[`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) is a type of `std::istream` so the function declaration would look like

```
void fun(std::istream& inStream, std::ostream& outStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example in which used of `cin` and `cout` as either input and output `streams` :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(istream &in, ostream &out)
{
   int i;
   in >> i;
   out << "output :" << i << endl;
}

int main()
{
   func(cin, cout);
   return 0;
}
```

If you enter a number e.g `53` , output will be :

```
output :53
```